# Require either one of two methods, or both in abstract class

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance, methods, abstract-class

For example, I have this code:

```typescript
export abstract class AbstractButton {
    // Always have to provide this
    abstract someRequiredMethod(): void;

    // One need to provide one of these (or both)
    abstract setInnerText?(): void;
    abstract setInnerHTML?(): void;
}
```

I need a successor to implement `setInnerText()` or `setInnerHTML()`, or both.

How to achieve this using the powerfullest type system built by humans?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK.

Comment: An `abstract` class requires that subclasses implement **all** `abstract` methods, or themselves be `abstract`. This includes ones you've marked optional above: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacICEBXCCAewDsEBvAWACgFGkLIpD5SoAKASmoF969JglCs8CMAFMIASXLkpUACpSAHhAD8vAFwIAbqQCWAEwDcwpmNzxJM+YqgAJZQFkAMtp57Dpi3UE6ehQ0DAANBHUIKXITDGxxeCISCmoEAHp0hAAeAF5chABRKChOen4gA

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type alias which uses a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to discriminate which implementation should be required:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgZ2AJwIYGNgCECuxgD2AdgDwAqUEAHsBEQCYJQDkcBwAFs1AD5QsdgAWwA23Ps1o1uAXhZtOzAHxQZAKH4AyKAG8oCAkIgAlCAEccAS2QR6AWQicC9ABQBKAFxQAbgUv0oAF8NKG0XEP4KaloGJmZBUW4Afl19RwBJIiIIZAAJMjsAGXcvX38giKgvKJo6RhYpYGTUhAysnLJokp8-AOD+fi9dSv5W4Ezs5E6abrL6AG4RtPH2vILizx7-RYGK-jdFtXQRVAQmLABGKEshMBEIIyJgJngkNExcfGJdQKgAegAVFAAKLIZAEZBLAB+ULUAGETmcWJduJYiOgITZMCIQNdbvdHs9rk8cgAzDDQZivFAYbB4QikABECg4jKUzAAdCEyOBKSjrkwiOwoKcEJYAOZEVBwe5QQhy3ksPQGIymCzWWwOJyuTZzeZBTmVAAK4MgyFALBVJnMVhs9kcHGcqKYQksZzR4uJCsgyIu3DgeCgNnVdq9oB9zGVhmtIc1Ducs16+sCnJcACYACxpgAMbigAL+aiOiPOabxdwedCJ1PedK+pFY7C4Kh0v0BILBEOhsIRouRadR6MxEGxuJuFcJTDRtGQ5PQlJrtM+DJIzKbbMNkUVzCwA4FUCFwBF7sl0tl8vDlKjqptGvt2sT2wNXN2JoIZotzCtattce1zqgV13SIT00W9Pk9wDI9g1-AIwMvJV9GjH87y1R0dVKJNn3TLNc3zQtiz7LAAGZywJKsXkQGkPnpYgSHiYQxBbNsgVBcFIV2fgYXhEtkWIwcMTBEdgBxMjKyeKcSVnCkWEXGj61XBIRA3F8oB5CMSIAw9jzFU8ZWgC9t2vGNYLQhNdSwlNVP4N8P1xL9kNvO0zPoACgLFECw23TSoCgoMnNsLyI2MlDnPjDCtgWbDMxzPMCyLY4iIzMTJ1gKja2XOjJGiZQfn+VjOw4zjuN7JEdwzATh1HFKKOJGc5wXdKl1oplGhU7lvIq-dtNFCUpX0uUCHAxDvwC+90MfKKrONU0ck-UbY3Gp193cj0gr5Lq-Jgu91pGxzFpcybk1TGK8PiwikSwABWGqJLSt5moUhjEhbfKO3Y7seL7HcrsqoTqvHci7unMkZKpJr5JXRklParcNN+7rhV6vTzyGhDI2WCYcnyIojufGb3zm+yxixtYijct0PNAohhp+-1A220N4KMzHVhxjZMKfKycNi-CQgW0zwsmn41GCC7zgANlu6sIbrFdnqY1I-j+KACAAa35-bBYfCzylbfm2kmdnhf1sXEsugB2aXKIeyGssaXK9HbNiu04qASt4ncLb+rERLHfFxKJEHpPnWTZcy1rolhtTvO9xGj2R-rUdp5VDY6LpdamzcBlsonLTTqYcpWym1uZjS462sbdoxknVmmYA8e5064sLUYtdQoXM5Fs3eKwAAOa37uouX7Zy17ldVjW25vA7O85gJ9dGAv65N4Ie6IgBOQe5JHmmnYKj63Y976sA3n3hNEwHA8k+qwZ3iPVxZaP1L5M-450vqzwMtGWdryYV8zvqP+2N1iN2znDV+FNgKek4NAUkBARAiAIAAdzWmAWa5pLAQCYKScEQgU6s3-hneeQCC7G0AQaLwwDC40AADSEJAbjZufNp4mQ7jree3cEq9wuNmbe4cWpKwPq7YqPZPaXGzOfAGAdUrBwamHW2u9H7rnZKpF+vpJHv0Tl-QaBDqEAJIQwsmHNIrHWslAXO5pibLyLm6QCJdPJlz5Lw+m0Eq5OJGjYmYFDqHkMMU3XCbg1BojAHgDkzwqAuAtvQi2mwvxeKaPuegI4Tihg4DkCAHIWFIRntrCaXdF5GL8ZFLh4soCXCuFfVK99BH73eiI3Yx8yoVKkX7Qeci74CIUmuTgz9vIXD9Fok8Sdv56ISXjXxoCKHTVfBg+aZD1hQKptXFpvkGbuJpujVOKwiHeMMZM3G0yTqBOyQLdh+TOGFP0cQkpptuFEQuGWKptUan1iVirdWmtcnnPMpc-oRSpl-INjs9OezblrzUEAA)

```ts
type AbstractButton<T extends 'both' |  'html' | 'text' = 'both'> =
  & { someRequiredMethod(): void }
  & (
    T extends 'html' ? { setInnerHTML(): void }
    : T extends 'text' ? { setInnerText(): void }
    :  {
      setInnerText(): void;
      setInnerHTML(): void;
    }
  );
```

Then you can use the [`implements`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses) clause to ensure conformance. Here are a few demonstrative examples from the TypeScript playground link above — check it out for a more exhaustive set:

```ts
class B5 implements AbstractButton<'html'> { /* Error
      ~~
Class 'B5' incorrectly implements interface 'AbstractButton<"html">'.
  Type 'B5' is not assignable to type '{ setInnerHTML(): void; }'.
    Property 'setInnerHTML' is missing in type 'B5' but required in type '{ setInnerHTML(): void; }'.(2420) */
  someRequiredMethod(): void {}
}

class B6 implements AbstractButton<'html'> { // ok
  someRequiredMethod(): void {}
  setInnerHTML(): void {}
}

class B7 implements AbstractButton<'text'> { /* Error
      ~~
Class 'B7' incorrectly implements interface 'AbstractButton<"text">'.
  Type 'B7' is not assignable to type '{ setInnerText(): void; }'.
    Property 'setInnerText' is missing in type 'B7' but required in type '{ setInnerText(): void; }'.(2420) */
  someRequiredMethod(): void {}
}

class B10 implements AbstractButton { /* Error
      ~~
Class 'B10' incorrectly implements interface 'AbstractButton<"both">'.
  Type 'B10' is not assignable to type '{ setInnerText(): void; setInnerHTML(): void; }'.
    Property 'setInnerText' is missing in type 'B10' but required in type '{ setInnerText(): void; setInnerHTML(): void; }'.(2420)
input.tsx(7, 7): 'setInnerText' is declared here. */
  someRequiredMethod(): void {}
  setInnerHTML(): void {}
}

class B12 implements AbstractButton { // ok
  someRequiredMethod(): void {}
  setInnerHTML(): void {}
  setInnerText(): void {}
}
```

Comment: Good option if they don't need `AbstractButton` to be a `class`. I figured they did for some reason, but hopefully not. :-)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75099818/require-either-one-of-two-methods-or-both-in-abstract-class/75100960#comment132530140_75100960) @T.J.Crowder Yeah, the real value of [abstract classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members) still eludes me. I understand the nominal value (e.g. with `instanceof` checks)... are you aware of others?

Comment: Partial implementation I think. The class in the question is completely abstract (but probably just pared down), but generally the only time I'd use one would be if I had concrete methods to implement and only a couple of subclass-specific methods. That said, I don't recall the last time I wrote one...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get a compile-time error, but it's ugly enough you may just want to require a mixin or similar, or just live with only a runtime test (throwing from the `AbstractButton` constructor), which will after all show up *very* early in the development of a subclass. (I show an example of the runtime check below, since you'll want it in any case even with the compile-time check for reasons described below.)

But I'll detail how I managed to get it to give me a compile-time error.

First, though, you can't define those optional abstract methods that way, they'll be required even though you have `?` on them ([playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacICEBXCCAewDsEBvAWACgFGkLIpD5SoAKASmoF969JglCs8CMAFMIASXLkpUACpSAHhAD8vAFwIAbqQCWAEwDcwpmNzxJM+YqgAJZQFkAMtp57Dpi3UE6ehQ0DAANBHUIKXITDGxxeCISCmoEAHp0hAAeAF5chABRKChOen4gA)). So we'll need to define the base class without them and then find a way to ensure subclasses have at least one of them. So now our base class is just:

```typescript
abstract class AbstractButton {
    // Always have to provide this
    abstract someRequiredMethod(): void;
}
```

I don't think you can do what you want to do purely with `class ___ extends AbstractButton`, but you can ensure a compile-time error with a do-nothing function that will cause a type error if the subclass doesn't implement at least one of those methods.

First, we need a helper mapped type to check to see if a constructor function's prototype has either of those methods:

```typescript
type CheckRequired<Ctor> =
    [Ctor] extends [ { prototype: { setInnerText: () => void; } } ]
    ? Ctor
    : [Ctor] extends [ { prototype: { setInnerHTML: () => void; } } ]
    ? Ctor
    : {__error__: "AbtractButton subclasses must implement `setInnerText` and/or `setInnerHTML`"}};
```

We could make those checks more stringent (for instance, prevent a class from implementing a valid `setInnerText` but an invalid `setInnerHTML` [invalid because it takes different params than you want), but that's the general shape of it.

The fact we're testing tuples (`[Ctor] extends ___`, not `Ctor extends ___`) is important, more about that later.

Okay, now we need a function that does nothing but does typecheck what it gets:

```typescript
function checkAbstractButtonSubclass<T>(cls: CheckRequired<T>) {}
```

Now, unfortunately, we have to require people to code a call to that in order to get the type error:

```typescript
checkAbstractButtonSubclass(SomeButtonSubclass);
```

Here's a series of classes with the calls — note that the call for `Neither` causes a type error because `Neither` doesn't implement either `setInnerText` or `setInnerHTML`:

```typescript
class Both extends AbstractButton {
    someRequiredMethod() { }
    setInnerText() { }
    setInnerHTML() { }
}
checkAbstractButtonSubclass(Both); // <== No error, it provides both

class JustText extends AbstractButton {
    someRequiredMethod() { }
    setInnerText() { }
}
checkAbstractButtonSubclass(JustText); // <== No error, it provides one of them

class JustHTML extends AbstractButton {
    someRequiredMethod() { }
    setInnerHTML() { }
}
checkAbstractButtonSubclass(JustHTML); // <== No error, it provides one of them

class Neither extends AbstractButton {
    someRequiredMethod() { }
}
checkAbstractButtonSubclass(Neither); // <== Error, it doesn't provide either:
// Argument of type 'typeof Neither' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ __error__: "AbtractButton subclasses must implement `setInnerText` and/or `setInnerHTML`"; }'
```

Having to code a pointless function call to get a compile-time type error is obviously less than ideal, but I don't think you can do it without. I did try to come up with a way to make the function call useful in some way, but unless you require a registration step for subclasses, I haven't figured one out yet. Maybe someone smarter than me will. :-)

Since people **will** forget to code that call, you'll want the `AbstractButton` constructor to do a runtime check as a backstop to the compile-time check (so it fails early in development if the coder doesn't write the call to `checkAbstractButtonSubclass`), something like:

```
constructor() {
    if (
        (!("setInnerText" in this) || typeof this.setInnerText !== "function") &&
        (!("setInnerHTML" in this) || typeof this.setInnerHTML !== "function")
    ) {
        throw new Error(
            "AbstractButton subclasses must implement either setInnerText or setInnerHTML. " +
            "You can use checkAbstractButtonSubclass(YourClass) to get a proactive compile-time " +
            "error for this instead of this runtime error."
        );
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacICEBXCCAewDsEBvAWACgFGEB6ZrZAd2AE8MALYADcApgjIIADlFKCAlgBNREPrLD0mCUJBjwEYUgFthAJWEBHQrKjD5AWWHLS8gBQBKAFwJBpBQG56AL709BDcEqIAwnzCsADWphZWNgA8EWRQAHwIALzqTADaaaRQALoIwgAeEMLk8hj51JLSZKHhnlR6DgCS5OTCUAAqlRCebjlZ3n4IAdMIJXmMAPwIRVALCJ6F6WXDNXUIDR1SpC1hwu2dED19UAASA7YAMqOu414+8r6zM-MMTMurdbtAD6wP60igoM8ACJsLh4EQSBQ9IQQCg0GBhBgDIRIAhZAYJMhhEZyIgAAaYq69fpDKrkzS1ZjFBCU7o0u4PR7k6EBAL+Oj0ABmhHI8FkyNg0Ti2G0eERZHIAGVUej0MkBhlnBVPFEYvFzJZrPINRlXlQgoK6GqMPgTnxylU9hhZfCCMRFdR1vojAkjTZ7I4XObpt72Tc6RAxh1LRoqdd+vcntHQ3RLVL9a6dO6kcrVah0M47cpXF9WAhktlsggAHKkcpQCEAGnxiGOckUGBA9uC1oLGAAUriIJHHdVai6cNmFcjaH9GD6TIaknYHHwnCnY0x4xzI5vAvQMzKp-KPRQVWj+84h5BI6WWGxK9W6w3m62mjIFFiEBRRKQhWI0QGL2NoIDeEBJo8Y7OlgJ4ImelBznGhhLokxqBuuwaNFuC7homXL7mmh7SrEWanrmF42tew6Qfe5ZPrW9bgsULayG20gdt+v4-gBygkiB-a1sIbHRFA0ETrBcrwbmXrznoKF+iuGEbiGlrpiRZHSYqlFXjWwl8VAdGPlWCAAKKNix77yKQWLkAA5Oxn6KOUIn9O49DlpgUAAOaEKSiD-mIZwIA5ZyBXprlQHZ+IYOQJyaOgsjeeQoDEmI9YSMAMBGNUYmBa0oh2R0oLMZCwIwnC04ISil4Yt+OJ4gSRIkjUFI7hGwwMsATIsmy1I3JBPJfAEdn0EAA)

Finally: So why is the utility type checking `[Ctor]` against `[{ prototype: { ___ } }]` instead of just testing `Ctor` against `{ prototype: ____ }`? Because we need to prevent the generic type argument from being *distributed*, because it breaks the tests. By wrapping it in a tuple, we disable the distribution.

But again, that's really ungainly and complicated, and a simple runtime check in the `AbstractButton` constructor without all the extra stuff will show up very early in the development of a subclass, so I think I'd probably just be happy with that.